# Mapbox set icon for featureLayer

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am having some problems with setting an icon for a feature layer. I keep getting `layer.setIcon is not a function` and similar errors. How can I change the icon style for this layer?

```
 var layer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
            .loadURL(attrs.geoJsonSource)
            .addTo(map);

        layer.on('ready', function() {
            this.eachLayer(function(layer){
                layer.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                    'marker-color': '#8834bb',
                    'marker-size': 'large',
                    'marker-symbol': 'restaurant'
                }))
            });
            map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());
        });
```

Comment: Where do you want to store the marker style ? On geoJSON side or directly in the web page side ?

Comment: Web page side yes

Comment: So have you tried to use the "FIRST" method bellow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why, but none of the proposed solutions work for me. Instead I have to iterate through the layers of the layer.

```
        layer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
            var marker = e.layer, feature = marker.feature;
            e.layer.getLayers().forEach(function(marker) {
                marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                    'marker-color': '#8834bb',
                    'marker-size': 'large',
                    'marker-symbol': 'restaurant'
                }));
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-marker/ and http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/ to get more information, but apparently you may fit your need:

- using **your own icon style**.  (FIRST)

and/or

- using **geoJSON file icon style**.  (SECOND)

The code:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets').setView([40, -74.50], 9);
var layer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

layer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var marker = e.layer,feature = marker.feature;

    // TWO POSSIBILITIES

    // FIRST // your own method to define how icon will be rendered   
    marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
        'marker-color': '#8834bb',
        'marker-size': 'large',
        'marker-symbol': 'restaurant' 
    }));

    // SECOND // use json directly to define how icon will be rendered   
    //marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon(feature.properties.icon));
});

layer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);
```

assuming the geoJSON file look like this:

```
var geoJson = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-75.00, 40]
    },
    "properties": {
        "title": "Small astronaut",
        "icon": {
            'marker-color': '#0034bb',
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'restaurant' 
        }
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-74.00, 40]
    },
    "properties": {
        "title": "Big astronaut",
        "icon": {
            'marker-color': '#8834bb',
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'restaurant' 
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the simple style spec to style the geojson. Looks like this needs to happen before you add it to the feature layer. You could try running eachLayer instead of the for loop, then adding that layer to another feature layer, once the geojson has the style/icons you want. This is modified from the original [example](https://www.mapbox.com/help/markers/). Or you could just use the Leaflet pointToLayer function as shown below.

```js
var key = 'your key here'
L.mapbox.accessToken = key;
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
  .setView([37.8, -96], 3);

var geojson = [
  {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [-77.031952, 38.913184]
    },
    properties: {
      title: 'Title'
    }
  }
 ];
//Option A - set the properties of the geojson using the simple style spec supported in mapbox.js for mapbox feature layers

/*for(i = 0; i < geojson.length; i++) {
  geojson[i].properties['marker-color'] = '#63b6e5';
  geojson[i].properties['marker-size'] = 'large';
  geojson[i].properties['marker-symbol'] = 'rocket';
}*/

//Option B - use the native leaflet function for points - very simple and extendable to other icon plugins
var features = L.geoJson(geojson, { 
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){
    return new L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
        'marker-color': '#00f',
        'marker-symbol': 'star'
        })
    })
  }
 }).addTo(map);
```

```css
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    .map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.4.0/mapbox.js"></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.4.0/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<div id='map' class='map'></div>
```

Comment: But why should my data be aware of how it is being rendered? Cant the style be changed progrematically?

Comment: Right, it's goofy I think, but that's a feature of mapbox.js. You might just want to use the normal L.geoJson() with the pointToLayer method above. Notice how this does not utilize the simplestyle-spec since it is not a mapbox feature layer.

Comment: @malcolm you may probably remove your access token from the answer (everybody could use it now ...)

Comment: The accepted answer is basically the same answer as mine, except I use the pointToLayer function in L.geoJson and not the mapbox feature layer. Both functions do the exact same thing! The question was not  how to use the setIcon() function, but just how to change the icon.